# Android expiry time of In-app subscription item in android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscriptions

I am trying to get expiry time or status of subscription to ensure if user is paying regularly for my item or not . When i query using

```
Purchase monthlySubscription = inv.getPurchase("itemName");
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
```

It returns following data

```
{  
       "packageName":"com.abcPackage",
       "productId":"auto1week",
       "purchaseTime":1453369299644,
       "purchaseState":0,
       "developerPayload":"PAY_LOAD",
       "purchaseToken":"TOKEN",
       "autoRenewing":true
}
```

The problem is , purchaseTime remains same after several weeks which is supposed to be change after every purchase.

I tried google Play developers API

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#subscriptions

but i am having a hard time implementing it on my android device .

I will be grateful if someone can guide me step by step process to get this data on android device.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Delete the developer payload and purchase token.

Comment: I noticed the same thing with my test purchases.  It seems the "purchaseTime" is always the time of the first purchase for a subscription.  I can't find much information out there about this regarding it updating for ever purchase.  I think the only real option at the moment is to hook up to the API and validate the purchase there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but here is my server side code (in java) that connects to the developer API and returns the expiration of the subscription.

I created a Service Account in the Google Developer Console, and followed the somewhat obtuse instructions to create a key file in src/resources/keys.json.  APPLICATION_NAME is the package name of my app, and PRODUCT_ID is the subscription ID from the Google PLAY developer console.

Sorry it's not really 'step by step' as you asked for, but I also am doing verification on the server side instead of on the client.  I suppose on the client you could do some sort of soft-verification by checking purchaseState == 0 (1=cancelled, 2=refunded), and autoRenewing==true.  You may get stuck there if they cancel though, since you are still supposed to provide service through the duration of the subscription.

```
    public static Long doSomeWork(String token){
        log.debug("Google Validation: Doing some work:" + token);

        try{
            // Creating new Trusted Transport
            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

            // Getting Auth Creds
            Credential cred = getAuthCredential();

            // Building Android Publisher API call
            AndroidPublisher ap = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, cred)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

            // Get Subscription
            AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get get = ap.purchases().subscriptions().get(
                    APPLICATION_NAME,
                    PRODUCT_ID,
                    token);

            SubscriptionPurchase subscription = get.execute();
            log.debug(subscription.toPrettyString());

            log.debug("DONE (not null)");
            return subscription.getExpiryTimeMillis();

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();
        }

        log.debug("DONE (failure) (0)");
        return 0L;

    }

    private static Credential getAuthCredential(){

        log.debug("getAuthCredential");
        try{
            //Read the credentials from the keys file.  This file is obtained from the
            // Google Developer Console (not the Play Developer Console
            InputStream is = GoogleReceiptValidation.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keys.json");
            String str = IOUtils.toString(is);
            is.close();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.toString().getBytes());

            //This is apparently "beta functionality".
            GoogleCredential creds = GoogleCredential.fromStream(stream);
            creds = creds.createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));

            return creds;
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException ex2){
            ex2.printStackTrace();
        }

        log.debug("No Creds found - returning null");

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but i do not need server side code.